# Elementary OS and Tray Icons

Tags: release-freya, icons, wingpanel

I have been a long time Ubuntu user. 3 weeks ago, I decided to give Elementary OS a try.

My initial experience was pretty good, but after the following changes, I was very happy.

- Elementary Tweaks to enable OSX style window controls
- Misc. GUI tweaks
- Linux 4.1.2 kernel (Really speeds up the whole OS.. Highly
  recommended)

The biggest issue that I am running into is with the tray icons. For example, I am trying to use the Citrix Receiver to access my enterprise application. The application installs fine, but the tray icon is non-existent. If you launch the application, it works great until you close it. After closing it, there application continues to run in the background thinking that you can just click on the tray icon(which we don't have). I have tried killing all of the Receiver processes, but you have to physically restart the whole machine before you can use Receiver again.

Any ideas why this is happening? I would love to use this more in the Enterprise, but this one little problem is what prevents me from moving forward.